# Write setting.bundle in runtime

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, settings.bundle

I can write at design time a setting bundle, but I need to make its content appear according to certain condition

can I do that , if yes any sample code, and where to put this code

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically create a Settings.bundle and write it out while your application is running on the iPhone.  It needs to be included in the *code signed* application package.

What you can do, though, is customize your already created bundle's content & UI based on those certain conditions.  E.G. different preferences load different strings or graphics.

Comment: for example using preprocessor condition :)